# How to Attach image file in Local Report(RDLC)?

Tags: winforms, reportviewer, rdlc, localreport

In Reporting Services Report(rdl) Image can be attached easily using Select the image Source and Use this image (Import) .

But when i create a local Report (rdlc) the options on rdl is not provided. So i cannot attached my .jpeg image on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a static image you can simply navigate to Report -> Embedded Images in Visual Studio and click 'New Image' to add a new image.

Comment: After Doing this what is the next step that i need to do that the picture will appear in the image control?

Comment: There is an image control you add to the report.

Comment: @johnryan And all the embedded images in the report will be selectable in the property page of that control.

Comment: Thanks i got it. on its value Property Just Add Expression : ="(ImageName)"